# Can't link Android app with Play Games Service via Google Play Developer Console; "an unexpected error occurred"

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-play-games, google-developers-console

I'm trying to setup my app to have sign in with Google Play Games Services. I created the games services app via the Google Play Developer console just fine, but at the step where I have to link my Android app, I get the following error screen in the site after I enter in my release/debug cert and package name and hit "confirm".

[image]

I've never gotten this error before, and I have used the Play Games Services sign-in before (albeit not that recently). Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think this is much better to ask to their tech support department. But did you retry and experience the same error?

Comment: Yeah I retried, but got the same error. Used Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Comment: Do you have their tech support contact handy? I can't seem to find where I would contact them

Comment: If you do not specify http in the URL it will default to https. If your site is not setup for https you will get this error. Just one possibility.